# Vim plugin Nudge Lines

Tags: plugin, vimscript, vim

I've published a Vim plugin that nudges visually selected lines up or down, which for the most part seems to function as designed. However, I believe there are likely ways that this plugin could be improved.

---

### Questions

- How do I register a movement that takes an optional amount?

> In other words how can this plugin differentiate between <kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><sub>^</sub><kbd>J</kbd></kbd> and <kbd><kbd>3</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><sub>^</sub><kbd>J</kbd></kbd>?

- Have I made any critical mistakes?
- Are there any features that should be added?

---

### Requirements

This plugin is tested on Linux based operating systems, but suggestions on how to make it OS agnostic are certainly welcomed; regardless Vim should be installed prior to using this plugin, eg...

```
sudo apt-get install vim
```

---

### Setup

[Source code](https://github.com/vim-utilities/nudge-lines) is maintained on GitHub, as are the documentation files and [`README.md`](https://github.com/vim-utilities/nudge-lines/blob/main/.github/README.md). Included within this question are the TLDR and source `.vim` script code files.

```
mkdir -vp ~/git/hub/vim-utilities

cd ~/git/hub/vim-utilities

git clone git@github.com:vim-utilities/nudge-lines.git
```

If **not** utilizing some form of Vim plugin manager, then the [`linked-install.sh`](https://github.com/vim-utilities/nudge-lines/blob/main/linked-install.sh) script may be run on most 'nix devices...

```
./linked-install.sh
```

... which will symbolically link plugin scripts and documentation, and update Vim documentation tags.

---

### Usage

After visually selecting a line, or range of lines, use the following keyboard shortcuts:

- <kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><sub>^</sub><kbd>k</kbd></kbd> Nudge visual selection up
- <kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><sub>^</sub><kbd>K</kbd></kbd> Nudge visual selection up and reformat tabs
- <kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><sub>^</sub><kbd>j</kbd></kbd> Nudge visual selection down
- <kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><sub>^</sub><kbd>J</kbd></kbd> Nudge visual selection down and reformat tabs

---

### Source Code

[**`plugin/nudge-lines.vim`**](https://github.com/vim-utilities/nudge-lines/blob/main/plugin/nudge-lines.vim)

```
#!/usr/bin/env vim


vnoremap <S-K> :call Nudge_Selection__Laterally(-1, 'reformat')<CR>
vnoremap <C-K> :call Nudge_Selection__Laterally(-1)<CR>

vnoremap <S-J> :call Nudge_Selection__Laterally(1, 'reformat')<CR>
vnoremap <C-J> :call Nudge_Selection__Laterally(1)<CR>


""
" Nudges visually selected lines up or down
" @param {number} a:amount - Signed integer of lines to nudge selection by
" @param {string[]} a:0 - Optionally reformat tabs
" @example
"   :'<,'> call Nudge_Selection__Laterally(-1, 'reformat')
" @author S0AndS0
" @license AGPL-3.0
function! Nudge_Selection__Laterally(amount, ...) abort range
  let l:not_visual_mode = visualmode() != 'V'
  let l:at_limits__lower = a:lastline == line('$')
  let l:at_limits__upper = a:firstline == 1
  if l:not_visual_mode
  \ || (a:amount > 0 && l:at_limits__lower)
  \ || (a:amount < 0 && l:at_limits__upper)
    normal! gv
    return
  endif

  if a:amount > 0
    let l:move_command = "'>+" . a:amount
  elseif a:amount < 0
    let l:move_command = "'<-" . (1 - a:amount)
  else
    throw 'amount must be greater or less than 0'
  endif

  execute "'<,'>move " . l:move_command

  if a:0 == 0
    normal! gv
  else
    normal! gv=gv
  endif

  silent! foldopen!
endfunction
```

> Side note, I'm not sure what's going on with syntax highlighting here, but as of latest revisions this plugin seem to function without error.

Comment: Let me compare to copy feature (`y` shortcut). You usualy press y And then an up or down arrow, optionally some numbers between to denote number of lines. Yours could behave similary. Visualy select lines, press Shift+j, nothing happens yet, press arrow up, all moves one line up, press 6 and arrow down, all moves 6 lines down... Its more flexible IMHO And you have saved Shift+k for a different feature...